# Selectable list of users in Django?

Tags: django, forms

### models.py

```
class EmployeeReportRequestForm(forms.Form):
    
    EMPLOYEECHOICE = []
    employees = User.objects.filter(group_name='rep')

    for employee in employees:
        EMPLOYEECHOICE.append([employee.get_username(), employee.get_full_name()])
        
    employee_choice = forms.CharField(max_length=50, widget=forms.Select(choices=EMPLOYEECHOICE))
    start_date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget())
    end_date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget())
```

Trying make a form that allows someone to make a selection from a list of users in a particular group, I figured this would work, but it is not.  The most info I'm able to get error wise is

"django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet."

I'm assuming my issue is trying to query the User database from within a Model and that I need to run the lines of code that generate the EMPLOYEECHOICE list in a view and then somehow pass that to the Model? Or just define the widget to be used in the View?

Answer (score 0):

### models.py

```
class EmployeeRequestForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self):              
        self.choice_list = [('test', 'test'),]        
        self.employees = User.objects.filter(groups__name='rep')        
        for self.x in self.employees:
            self.choice_list.append([self.x.get_username(), self.x.get_full_name()])        
        self.CHOICES = self.choice_list
        super (EmployeeRequestForm, self).__init__()
        self.fields['employee_choice'].widget = forms.Select(choices=self.CHOICES)         
    employee_choice = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    start_date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget())
    end_date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget())
```

Figured out what I was doing wrong, needed to define the choices within the **init** method.  Not sure if this is the best way to do it, but it works.